# Polymer - Producing cards on large screens and plain text on small screens?

Tags: polymer

thanks for reading this and helping out a complete stranger.

Essentially, I am trying to replicate what Google says in their material design document using polymer, recreating this effect http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/images/materialdesign-goals-landingimage_large_mdpi.png

Sadly, I've had no success, I had originally though that such a feature would be built in Polymer (Please correct me if I'm wrong). Anyway, thanks for your help, and here is the source code https://github.com/Rijul-Ahuja/Rijul-Ahuja.github.io/tree/master/Enactus

Comment: Please post your source code here and specify what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for core-media-query

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-media-query

edit: added a video on how to use it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svfu9iQ8cyg